# Download progress with VBS and batch

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I just found this nice [VBS code](http://failiem.lv/down.php?i=rljfqvy&n=data.vbs) which allows download some file from an address I was include in the VBS code:

```
Download "www.someadress.com", "c:\file.ext"

Sub Download(sSource,sDest)

    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    set oHTTP = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    oHTTP.open "GET", sSource, False
    oHTTP.send
    set oStream = createobject("adodb.stream")

    oStream.type = adTypeBinary
    oStream.open
    oStream.write oHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.savetofile sDest, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    set oStream = nothing
    set oHTTP = nothing

End sub
```

But although the script works, it runs silently: I can't see any window, pop-ups or anything. When the file is downloaded then it shows in its folder.

I want create a batch window with `somebat.bat` and my VBS file. For example I run my .bat file and in this window it shows the text `"Downloading new file"` and the percent of download, like `"Downloading new file .. 10%"`.

Is that possible by just editing and using my VBS and a .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing "Downloading new file" with the name of the file is no problem but showing its progress is. You would need a method that makes it possible to chop your download in pieces that you can measure and plot on a scale, be it a graphical progress bar or a text based counter. The best solution is to use an external utility like wget which has such feature or use a language which is better suited for such taks such as Ruby, a natural step up for Vbscripters.